# Bond energy in hydrogen

Tags: inorganic-chemistry

Why is hydrogen-hydrogen bond the **strongest** of all single bonded compounds?

The bond energy principle here is based on the stability of atom after bonding, so even other atoms, when they combine with some other atoms and form covalent bonds, they would attain stability,

In what way is this different from that?

Is **doublet** configuration more stable than the **octet** configuration?

Or is there a totally different explanation lying?

Comment: Can you add numbers to your question? Bond energy of H-H, C-H, O-H, ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly the bond is non polar covalent bond ( as there is no difference in electronegativity of both hydrogen atoms). Secondly , the small size of the atoms also play a major role. Since the size of hydrogen atom is so small so the bond pair of electrons is bound by the electrostatic force of attraction between the electrons and nucleus. It can also be understood as the closer the electrons to the nuclei the more negative potential energy it possess which means more stability resulting in high bond energy.